# How can I login to Meteor with native device Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, node.js, meteor, meteorite

Suppose I logged into my device's Facebook authentication, like system Facebook on iOS. I obtain an `access token`.

How can I use the `access token` to login to Meteor's Facebook `Oauth` provider?

Comment: i suspect you can't, treat all ios apps as sandboxed and unaware of resources from other apps. no doubt i'll be proved wrong now. i'm not willing to enable the native facebook integration on my iphone so can't help you test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To login with Facebook using an access token obtained by another means, like iOS Facebook SDK, define a method on the server that calls the appropriate `Accounts` method:

```
$FB = function () {
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Cannot run on client.");
    }

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (args.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var path = args[0];
    var i = 1;
    // Concatenate strings together in args
    while (_.isString(args[i])) {
        path = path + "/" + args[i];
        i++;
    }

    if (_.isUndefined(path)) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'No Facebook API path provided.');
    }
    var FB = Meteor.npmRequire('fb');

    var fbResponse = Meteor.sync(function (done) {
        FB.napi.apply(FB, [path].concat(args.splice(i)).concat([done]));
    });

    if (fbResponse.error !== null) {
        console.error(fbResponse.error.stack);
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Facebook API error.", {error: fbResponse.error, request: args});
    }

    return fbResponse.result;
};

Meteor.methods({
    /**
     * Login to Meteor with a Facebook access token
     * @param accessToken Your Facebook access token
     * @returns {*}
     */
    facebookLoginWithAccessToken: function (accessToken) {
        check(accessToken, String);

        var serviceData = {
            accessToken: accessToken
        };

        // Confirm that your accessToken is you
        try {
            var tokenInfo = $FB('debug_token', {
                input_token: accessToken,
                access_token: Meteor.settings.facebook.appId + '|' + Meteor.settings.facebook.secret
            });
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Facebook login failed. An API error occurred.');
        }

        if (!tokenInfo.data.is_valid) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(503, 'This access token is not valid.');
        }

        if (tokenInfo.data.app_id !== Meteor.settings.facebook.appId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(503, 'This token is not for this app.');
        }

        // Force the user id to be the access token's user id
        serviceData.id = tokenInfo.data.user_id;

        // Returns a token you can use to login
        var loginResult = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService('facebook', serviceData, {});

        // Login the user
        this.setUserId(loginResult.userId);

        // Return the token and the user id
        return loginResult;
    }
}
```

This code depends on the `meteorhacks:npm` package. You should call `meteor add meteorhacks:npm` and have a `package.json` file with the Facebook node API: `{ "fb": "0.7.0" }`.

If you use `demeteorizer` to deploy your app, you will have to edit the output `package.json` and set the `scrumptious` dependency from `"0.0.1"` to `"0.0.0"`.

On the client, call the method with the appropriate parameters, and you're logged in!

In Meteor 0.8+, the result of `Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService` has changed to an object containing `{userId: ...}` and furthermore, no longer has the stamped token.

Comment: I tried this with Meteor 8.1.1, but it won't work.. Is this still supported?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `accessToken` in the `Meteor.user()` data at `Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken` (be aware this can only be accessed on the server side as the `services` field is not exposed to the client.

So when a user logs in with facebook on your meteor site these fields would be populated with the user's facebook data. If you check your meteor user's database with mongo or some other gui tool you could see all the fields which you have access to.

Comment: Hmm, I want to do the reverse—I have an `access token` and I want to login to Meteor `accounts` with it.

Comment: Do you mean a facebook access token or a meteor access token? It sounds like you said you want to get access to facebook's `OAuth` to get access to the graph api/fql

Comment: Facebook access token. I actually want access to Meteor's oauth consumer to login to Meteor using the Facebook access token.

Answer (score 1):

Building on DrPangloss' most excellent answer above, combining it with this awesome post: http://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html

You'll run into some issues using ObjectiveDDP in trying to get the client persist the login. Include the header:

```
#import "MeteorClient+Private.h"
```

And manually set the required internals. Soon I'll make a meteorite package and an extension to MyMeteor (https://github.com/premosystems/MyMeteor) but for now it's manual.

```
loginRequest: {"accessToken":"XXXXXb3Qh6sBADEKeEkzWL2ItDon4bMl5B8WLHZCb3qfL11NR4HKo4TXZAgfXcySav5Y8mavDqZAhZCZCnDDzVbdNmaBAlVZAGENayvuyStkTYHQ554fLadKNz32Dym4wbILisPNLZBjDyZAlfSSgksZCsQFxGPlovaiOjrAFXwBYGFFZAMypT9D4qcZC6kdGH2Xb9V1yHm4h6ugXXXXXX","fbData":{"link":"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10152179306019999/","id":"10152179306019999","first_name":"users' first name","name":"user's Full Name","gender":"male","last_name":"user's last name","email":"users@email.com","locale":"en_US","timezone":-5,"updated_time":"2014-01-11T23:41:29+0000","verified":true}}

Meteor.startup(
  function(){
    Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest) {
      //there are multiple login handlers in meteor.
      //a login request go through all these handlers to find it's login hander
      //so in our login handler, we only consider login requests which has admin field

      console.log('loginRequest: ' + JSON.stringify(loginRequest));

      if(loginRequest.fbData == undefined) {
        return undefined;
      }

      //our authentication logic :)
      if(loginRequest.accessToken == undefined) {
        return null;
      } else {
        // TODO: Verfiy that the token from facebook is valid...
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0#checktoken
        // graph.facebook.com/debug_token? input_token={token-to-inspect}&access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}

      }

      //we create a user if not exists, and get the userId
      var email = loginRequest.fbData.email || "-" + id + "@facebook.com";
      var serviceData = {
        id: loginRequest.fbData.id,
        accessToken: loginRequest.accessToken,
        email: email
      };
      var options = {
        profile: {
          name: loginRequest.fbData.name
        }
      };
      var user = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService('facebook', serviceData, options);

      console.log('Logged in from facebook: ' + user.userId);

      //send loggedin user's user id
      return {
        userId: user.userId
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer could be improved further as we can now directly debug the token from a REST http request using futures. Credit still goes to @DoctorPangloss for the principal steps necessary.

```
//Roughly like this - I removed it from a try/catch

        var future = new Future();
        var serviceData = {
              accessToken: accessToken,
              email: email
            };

            var input = Meteor.settings.private.facebook.id + '|' + Meteor.settings.private.facebook.secret
            var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=" + accessToken + "&access_token=" + input
            HTTP.call( 'GET', url, function( error, response ) {

                      if (error) {
                          future.throw(new Meteor.Error(503, 'A error validating your login has occured.'));
                      }

                      var info = response.data.data

                      if (!info.is_valid) {
                          future.throw(new Meteor.Error(503, 'This access token is not valid.'));
                      }

                      if (info.app_id !== Meteor.settings.private.facebook.id) {
                          future.throw(new Meteor.Error(503, 'This token is not for this app.'));
                      }

                      // Force the user id to be the access token's user id
                      serviceData.id = info.user_id;

                      // Returns a token you can use to login
                      var user = Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService('facebook', serviceData, {});
                      if(!user.userId){
                        future.throw(new Meteor.Error(500, "Failed to create user"));
                      }

                      //Add email & user details if necessary 
                      Meteor.users.update(user.userId, { $set : { fname : fname, lname : lname }})
                      Accounts.addEmail(user.userId, email)

                      //Generate your own access token!
                      var token = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken()
                      Accounts._insertLoginToken(user.userId, token);

                      // Return the token and the user id
                      future.return({
                        'x-user-id' : user.userId,
                        'x-auth-token' : token.token
                      })
            });

          return future.wait();
```

Use this instead of the JS lib suggested by @DoctorPangloss. Follow the same principles he suggested but this avoids the need to integrate an additional library